# configuration basic workbox

Tags: webpack, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Hello i want to try some basic configuration on [workbox](https://workboxjs.org/).
 webpack file part:

```
new workboxPlugin({
    globDirectory: DIST_DIR,
    globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js,css}'],
    swDest: path.join(DIST_DIR, 'sw.js'),
}),
```

gives me sw.js

```
    importScripts('workbox-sw.prod.v2.0.1.js');    
    const fileManifest = [
          {
            "url": "bundle.js",
            "revision": "84672073db22fef0c8901d059044b7f2"
          },
          {
            "url": "js/index.js",
            "revision": "74ca2d3205fd59dffc0e7245643f7872"
          },
          {
            "url": "main.css",
            "revision": "ecce481ad315950d06e887ad1327bdf3"
          },
  {
    "url": "../index.html",
    "revision": "ecce481ad315950d06e887ad1327bdf3"
  }
        ];

        const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW();
        workboxSW.precache(fileManifest);
```

on cache i see info:
[image]

Still when i go for page in offline mode i cant see anything. Is that mean that service worker is not working ? or my config is bad ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you testing? By default, the generated SW won't control the window client when the SW is initially registered. If you're just loading the page, going offline and then hitting Reload, the SW won't be in control. You can navigate away and then come back to the page and then test again. Alternatively, if you want the SW to take control immediate, you can set `skipWaiting: true` and `clientsClaim: true` in your configuration.

Comment: i add prams, also change script to have dev messages. I can see all dev info but only at start after i refresh i not see it until i unregistered worker. I have xampp using localhost. When i go offline mode i see page breaks it should not happend i gess ?

Comment: Do you register the service worker on your index.html?

Answer (score 0):

while your current configuration adds all the bundles to cache-storage.
While you go to you web app "/" I guess sw cannot match the exact URL.

I guess need to add a key: `navigateFallback: index.html`(If yours is a SPA).

Now when you navigate to your web app any failure to navigate will open index.html for you.

Comment: I write my own config (not generated) and add url from doc and it worked. I try with that settings as well.